# $h:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\operatorname{h}(x,y)=\operatorname{g}(x^2-y^2,2xy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $h:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\operatorname{h}(x,y)=\operatorname{g}(x^2-y^2,2xy)$, where $g:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathrm{C^2}$ function that satisfies $\nabla \mathrm g \ne \mathrm 0 $ for every $\mathrm (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} $.
> Show that h has only one critical point $\mathrm(0,0)$ and classify it.

I tried using that $\mathrm 2x \frac{\partial g }{\partial x} \mathrm (x^2-y^2,2xy)  $ + $\mathrm 2y\frac{\partial g }{\partial y} \mathrm (x^2-y^2,2xy) =\mathrm 0$ and $\mathrm (-2y)\frac{\partial g }{\partial x} \mathrm (x^2-y^2,2xy) + \mathrm 2x \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \mathrm (x^2-y^2,2xy) =\mathrm 0$ and could arrive at that solution under the assumption that at least one of partial derivatives is different than zero. After that, I calculated the hessian determinant at that point $\mathrm (0,0)$ and arrived at that result:$\mathrm -4(a^2+b^2)$ where $ a=\frac{\partial g }{\partial x} \mathrm (0,0)$
$ b=\frac{\partial g }{\partial y} \mathrm (0,0)$, now using that $\nabla \mathrm g \ne \mathrm 0 $, we can conclude that $\mathrm -4(a^2+b^2)$ will be negative and $\mathrm(0,0)$ is a saddle point. Is this conclusion valid?

Comment: Why do you write "under the assumption that at least one of partial derivatives is different than zero"? This is not an additional assumption. It is the hypothesis $\nabla g \ne \mathrm 0.$ Apart from this detail, your answer is fine.

Comment: Sure, I misused it; it's just based on the initial hypothesis that the gradient of g is different than zero